# How to Synchronize the output of 2 FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I have instantiated 2 FileSystemWatcher, what I would like now is to synchronized the two filesystemwatcher. As of now here is an example output of logs: (Note the change of format refers to the other FSM vice versa)

```
Dec 15 15:28:19,8167876|: INFO   |Web server call start_device_discovery() for: 10.191.20.0
Dec 15 15:28:19,8167876|: START  |      Device discovery started for: 10.191.20.0
Dec 15 15:28:19,9261472|: INFO   |Discovery is active for: NET_10.191.20.0_24
Dec 15 15:28:20,1136208|: INFO   |Device discovered from NET_10.191.20.0_24 BaseModelName: "TASKalfa 250ci", ModelName: "TASKalfa 250ci", MoName: "TASKalfa 250ci"
Dec 15 15:28:20,3948312|: INFO   |Device discovered from NET_10.191.20.0_24 BaseModelName: "FS-C2626MFP", ModelName: "FS-C2626MFP", MoName: "FS-C2626MFP"
Dec 15 15:28:20,4260768|: INFO   |Device discovered from NET_10.191.20.0_24 BaseModelName: "FS-3640MFP", ModelName: "FS-3640MFP", MoName: "FS-3640MFP"
Dec 15 15:28:20,5198136|: INFO   |Device discovered from NET_10.191.20.0_24 BaseModelName: "TASKalfa 7550ci", ModelName: "TASKalfa 7550ci", MoName: "TASKalfa 7550ci"
Dec 15 15:28:20,6135504|: INFO   |Device discovered from NET_10.191.20.0_24 BaseModelName: "FS-C2626MFP", ModelName: "FS-C2626MFP", MoName: "FS-C2626MFP"
2011-12-15 15:28:19,785|  INFO | NetworkList - setStartDiscovery - Starting point
2011-12-15 15:28:19,785|  INFO | NetActionProvider - performAction - JYR
2011-12-15 15:28:19,785|  INFO | NetActionProvider - ATN_DISCOVERY_START
2011-12-15 15:28:19,785|  INFO | SNMPDiscovery - Starting discovery for NET_10.191.20.0_24.
```

Kindly look closely at their time. The statement with 15:28:19,8167876ms was first outputted before 15:28:19,785ms

```
Dec 15 15:28:19,8167876|: INFO   |Web server call start_device_discovery() for: 10.191.20.0
2011-12-15 15:28:19,785|  INFO | NetworkList - setStartDiscovery - Starting point
```

What I would like to do is somehow try to sync these 2 watchers. Any ideas? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Show pelase a code which writes to a file, perhaps something wrong in place where you specifying a DateTime value

Comment: Huh? Your question shows the lines as if they were in a single file. But, your comment below indicates that they are actually from 2 different files. So *how can* they possibly be out of order? Are you attempting to merge them? And what is this "Java-client" business you speak of? **This question is desperately lacking detail as it is.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to synchronize the log access. To do so, you need a simple object to synchronize on, which is accessible to all `FileSystemWatcher` event handlers. For simplification you could use the logger object (but read the [remarks section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).
Acquire a lock **as soon as the `FileSystemWatcher` gets notified**:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock(MyLogger)
    {
        MyLogger.Log("something changed");
    }
}
```

Make sure that you lock everywhere you use the logger.

Comment: Problem is, these are 2 different files logged by different languages (Java-client) and (C#-webservice)

Comment: Then you should update your question to be much more specific about your setup.